# Tracking daily user visits

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website. I want to track how many consecutive days a user has visited my website. Currently I have a code which tracks this in `Login` action but I can't track the users who've visited the website and have checked **"remember me"** in the login page. Needless to say, I'm looking for a way to achieve this with minimum possible performance hit.

Comment: Why cant you track them when they have remember me" selected. Don't you just do an auto login for them, when they are remembered?

Comment: Well, I don't exactly know how the Asp.Net Identity handles this. I can guess that it's being handled using a cookie which holds the authentication info. I don't know how I can examine this info. I don't want to check for it every single time a user loads a page. Also I want to handle cached pages properly.

Comment: How are you tracking this currently? You said: 

##Currently I have a code which tracks this in Login##

Comment: @LouisvanTonder When a user logins, I set the `DateTime.Now` as their latest login and check if they have logged in yesterday. If so, I add 1 to the consecutive logins, otherwise I set it to zero. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Does that routine not run when it auto logs in? Where do you intercept the login?

Comment: I have added my code to the `HTTP POST` version of the `Login` action in `UsersController`. The user has to explicitly call the `Login` action (using the login page) to run my code. I don't know how to examine this if they've already logged in few days earlier with the "Remember me" checkbox (hence, not loding the login page, they just don't need to)

Comment: Have you considered rolling your own login routine? I take it you are currently using .net memberships and rolls?

Comment: Since this is a very sensitive area, I'd stay away from doing it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

try Like this ,
When you track user login you might be storing users IP address or User name into database.

You can save date and time along with IP and User Name.

from this you can track the users who've visited the website.

Comment: Thanks but I'm already doing this. My problem is that I can't keep track of the user if they're already logged in yesterday (or before that) and are visiting my site without hitting the `Login` action. (if they've check the "remember me" checkbox)

Comment: Ok If they click remember me then just add counter

Comment: Add counter and on page load of home you can use Ticker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387844/c-sharp-asynchronous-task-for-a-stock-ticker  to increase counter

Comment: There is a possibility that the user visits the website without going to homepage. I would for a lot of websites. Also, that wouldn't be so good performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Models folder -> IdentityModels.cs 
In **ApplicationUser** class find **GenerateUserIdentityAsync** method. It is called both for straignt signin and cookies one.

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {  
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here

        return userIdentity;
    }
```

Cookies call goes from **StartupAuth.cs** class Startup -> ConfigureAuth -> app.UseCookieAuthentication -> Provider -> regenerateIdentity -> **user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)), 
                }
            });
```

Comment: Maybe it's because I've upgraded my MVC project from 4 version but I can't find this method. I also searched whole project (using`Ctrl+,`) but didn't find this.

Comment: I found a similar code in `SignInAsync` method but it wasn't called for signed-in users.

Comment: It's Identity 2. Cookies call is determined inside Startup.Auth.cs -> public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) -> Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider -> regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))

Comment: You can update Idenity up to 2 -> [Updating ASP.NET applications from ASP.NET Identity 1.0 to 2.0.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/updating-asp-net-applications-from-asp-net-identity-1-0-to-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx)

Comment: Acutally I have updated the Identity to 2 but the code in `ConfigureAuth` function is like this: `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, LoginPath = new PathString("/users/login") }`

Comment: You are missing CookieAuthenticationProvider - please check I've added code to the answer.

Comment: I added the code like above (I didn't have `CookieAuthenticationProvider` but I found its code and added it too) but the function never got hit (the `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` function). Am I missing something else?